# How to install node.js and create project in Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, windows, nodeclipse

The steps I've tried:
1.(OK) install node from official website: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Result: I'm able to open cmd(in any location, type node then use commands like "console.log" and it prints my messages)

2.(Failure) install express using `npm install -g express` from cmd gives me an error(picture attached[image]

3.(OK) I've succeed installing express using the following command `npm install express` (without -g)
4.(OK) Writing a simple Hello World program works. Javascript file:

```
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

5.(Failure) However, I wanna run a bigger project, where besides one js file, I also have an index.html file. If I move both files to node installation directory, everything works. But I wanna be able to keep my projects somewhere else. If I try to run with `node C:\Users\marius\Downloads\chat-example-master\indes.js` I get the error: `Cannot find module express`. Thus it seems that when I installed express without "-g" I got it working only in node directory.(let me know if you have any doubt).
6.(Failure) When creating a Node.js project from Eclipse, I choose empty project, no template, then add a single and simple js file(the one with Hello World), right click on project name -> run as -> run Configuration -> Node Application -> New -> add my .js file -> Run. I get the following error: 
Exception occurred executing command line.(steps from http://techprd.com/how-to-setup-node-js-project-in-eclipse/)

```
Cannot run program "node" (in directory "C:\Users\marius\workspace\FirstNodeProject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

To recap: What I want is to be able to run node projects located anywhere with "node" in cmd and to create node.js and express project and run them from Eclipse.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let others know if they come across this issue. I can run express apps from anywhere but in the root folder of every app I have to `npm install express`.
In Eclipse all you need to do is: Window->Preferences->Nodeclipse->uncheck "find .Node on PATH" and insert into Node.js path input your node.exe location (in my case: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)